# Select LIMIT 1 takes long time on postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm running a simple query on localhost PostgreSQL database and it runs too long:

```
SELECT * FROM features LIMIT 1;
```

I expect such query to be finished in a fraction of a second as it basically says "peek anywhere in the database and pick one row". Or it doesn't?

- table size is 75GB with estimated row count 1.84405e+008
- I'm the only user of the database
- the database server was just started, so I guess nothing is cached in memory

Comment: internally, the LIMIT is executed AFTER the SELECT is done, so it selects the whole table into memory, then picks the first one. With the size of your db, this takes long. Try to add some where clause which uses indexes.

Comment: can you attach result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM features LIMIT 1`. When `features` is really table, then this query should to read just 8KB.  Next question is - what is too long? how much?

Comment: "internally, the LIMIT is ... memory, then picks the first one." might be @Iarwa1n But the topicstarter is using `LIMIT` just plain wrong annyway without a `ORDER BY` "When using LIMIT, it is important to use an ORDER BY clause that constrains the ,,, unpredictable subset of the query's rows." ( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html ) I think the query will be more optimal when the SERIAL primary key column is been used in the query like `SELECT * FROM features ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;` then the query plan should change from `seq scan` into a `index scan`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think it is not on us to tell him what to select. Maybe he wants to pick any one entry without caring about which one it is.

Comment: I really don't understand why should seq scan be slower than index scan. The query says "take any single row". Just peek at first one and immediately return it. Why would it load more than a single row?

Comment: "internally, the LIMIT is executed AFTER the SELECT is done, so it selects the whole table into memory, then picks the first one." - PostgreSQL's planner should (and maybe IS) smarter than this. The doc says "The query optimizer takes LIMIT into account when generating query plans".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with @larwa1n with the content he comment on your post. 
The reason here, I guess, is the performance of `SELECT` is too slow.
With my experience maybe there are another reasons. I list as below:

- The table is too big, so let add some `WHERE CLAUSE` and `INDEX`
- The performance of your server/disk drive is too slow.
- Other process take most resource.
- Another reason maybe come from maintenance task, let check again does the `autovacuum` is running? If not, check is this table is `vacuum` already? If not, let do a `vacuum full` on that table. Sometimes, when you do a lot of insert/update/delete on a large table without `vacuum` will make the table save in fragmented disk block, which will take longer time in query.

Hopefully, this answer will help you find out the final reason.